# How does HKWorkoutActivityType contribute to a HKWorkout?

Tags: healthkit, watchos

When creating a HKWorkoutSession we need to provide a HKWorkoutConfiguration with a HKWorkoutActivityType.

There are many HKWorkoutActivityType available to use, but I don't find what is the application of it.

Does different type of activityType contribute different amount of totalEnergyBurned during the workout? or is it only used in querying the HealthKit for particular type of workout?

I am creating a general workout watchApp by which a user can just start and stop a workout to complete its rings. But I am confused by HKWorkoutActivityType. Will there be any difference in TotalEnergyBurned if I use different HKWorkoutActivityType, because it is contributing to close the red ring.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, HealthKit needs to know the HKWorkoutActivityType so that the workout is listed properly in Apple Health.  It does not automatically calculate the totalEnergyBurned or any other quantities used to characterize the workout:

> Your app should always provide data for the workout’s duration,
>   totalDistance, and totalEnergyBurned properties when the data is both
>   available and relevant to the workout. In addition, you should provide
>   a set of associated samples that sum up to these totals.

From: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/healthkit/hkworkout

I do not know whether HealthKit validates whether a quantity is appropriate for a given type of workout, e.g. wheelchair "pushes" when swimming.